# get key as well as value within foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am currently able to get the value from a php object array however I need to get the key too. The key is variable so I cannot manually define the key.

```
foreach($decodedItemMeta->meta as $meta_item){
    echo '<li> ';
    echo '<strong>[key here]</strong>';
    echo '<p>'.stripslashes($meta_item).'</p>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

print_r of $decodedItemMeta:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [meta] => stdClass Object ( 
        [Their name] => Name 
        [Their email] => ben@example.com 
        [Gift message] => It\'s a great day for bug testing! 
    ) 
    [product] => stdClass Object ( ) 
)
```

Comment: `foreach($decodedItemMeta->meta as $key => $meta_item) {`

Comment: [Documentation, documentation, documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you for the link @MarkBaker. I was having trouble searching for the right thing! Got this bookmarked for future use

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
foreach($decodedItemMeta->meta as $key=> $meta_item){
    echo '<li> ';
    echo '<strong>'.$key.'</strong>';
    echo '<p>'.stripslashes($meta_item).'</p>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.